# Processing frame every second in opencv python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, opencv

Here is the code for reading video file from webcam using opencv website. I just want to process the frame every second.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How should I modify the code:

Answer (score 0):

You should just make your process wait for one second before each read:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    start_time = time.time()
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    time.sleep(1.0 - time.time() + start_time) # Sleep for 1 second minus elapsed time

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Would be nice to take processing time into account

Comment: @DmitriiZ. It is possible performing `cap.read()` again and again and to skip frames, but it is very inefficient. Processing time is here extremely small compared to one second. Another possibility is to run a process every second getting a frame. However this requires a much larger transformation of the code.

Comment: Why not just add `start = time.time()` and `end = time.time()` and sleep for (1 - (end - start)) instead of 1? (also taking into consideration that processing time can be greater than 1s)

Comment: Good idea, I'll add that to my solution.

Comment: Is this really answering the question that was asked? I interpret the question as wanting to only *sample* from the video stream every second, and process it. Your solution will not skip any frames from a live network stream (i.e. an RTSP stream), every call to `cap.read()` will return the next frame in the sequence. How do you actually skip frames so you are sampling frames once per second?